# Localization of front-end template in Voyager Laravel

Tags: laravel, translation, voyager

I want to translate my blog template which was created in Voyager.
When I add new post I write it in only one language. Can you tell me step by step how to add translation to my posts? I want that the post translation could be changed from Voyager admin panel, not from file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SOLUTION

1. Change `config/voyager.php` multilang options
2. https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/pull/561